# What is your level of expertise?

Tags: discussion

Simple straw poll here. Upvote the answer that applies to you.

NB - [Meta-meta] - Are polls appropriate in meta discussion?

Comment: I think polls are appropriate. Question is how far to disaggregate. Perhaps you should've added the possible choices as answers, but now its too late :)

Answer (score 4):

I am a PhD Candidate in Economics.

Answer (score 1):

Hold a doctorate in economics and work as a practising academic economist.

Answer (score 1):

Doctorate, research economist.

Answer (score 1):

Undergrad degree including economics.  Masters in a sub-field of economics.

Answer (score 0):

I studied some undergrad economics at University, but am not otherwise involved.

Have a general interest in economics.

Answer (score 0):

Masters degree in economics. Working in the public sector. I have a general interest in economics.